# Is it correct to say "a context aware modeling of trust"?

Tags: grammar, terminology

> Towards a *context aware modeling of trust* and access control based on
>   the user behavior and capabilities

I was reading some documentation and this phrase stopped me! Is it correct after all?

Comment: It should probably have a hyphen in ***context-aware***. Is that all you're questioning? The word ***the*** before ***user*** is maybe a bit questionable, but not ridiculous.

Comment: If this is a title, *the* is wrong, since no user behaviour has yet been referred to. Context would be valuable, as ever.

Comment: @Tim: OP says "phrase".

Comment: @Fumble: the whole quote is a phrase...

Comment: [Context-aware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_awareness) means something in computer science, as does [modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation#Simulation_versus_model).

Comment: @TimLymington Huh. I was sure the whole phrase was a quote...  ;o)

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, now it make sense :/

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Agree with your whole comment. The whole thing is very CS jargony. It looks like a thesis, paper, or symposium title.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I assume OP has all the relevant context (which we lack, obviously). Me, I've no idea what kind of modelling *isn't* "context-aware" - it would seem to me that the whole point of a computer model is that you provide it with all the relevant starting data (i.e. *context*), then let it work out what might happen next. But we don't need to care about that, since it seems OP's problem lies in parsing the grammar, not understanding the jargon itself.

Answer (score 2):

The usage is correct, and meaningful in IT. See also [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html) by Ken Thompson - 1984.

You might also refer to the [Rainbow Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Series), which cover the Department of Defense standards for trusted systems.

[image: DoD Rainbow Books]